# Convert XML Type to VARCHAR

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am trying to convert the data extracted from XMLTYPE column to varchar but it gives me error:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (XML_DATA, '/root/MYData/text()'))
  FROM TBL_DATA
```

Gives error "Inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got - "

My motive is to put the extracted value into a variable and use it further in stored proc and the node can contain number or alphabets:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(EXTRACT (XML_DATA, '/root/MYData/text()')) INTO TEMP_VAR
  FROM TBL_DATA
```

Comment: It's complaining because the TO_CHAR() function is only used for numbers and dates. I think you want to get rid of it, and use the .getStringVal() function.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXTRACTVALUE` rather than `EXTRACT`:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0e76/7)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TBL_DATA ( XML_DATA ) AS
SELECT XMLTYPE( '<root><MYData>test string</MYData></root>' ) FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(XML_DATA, '/root/MYData/text()')
  FROM TBL_DATA
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0e76/7/0)**:

```
| EXTRACTVALUE(XML_DATA,'/ROOT/MYDATA/TEXT()') |
|----------------------------------------------|
|                                  test string |
```

**Query 2**:

However, [`EXTRACT` and `EXTRACTVALUE` are deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions069.htm#SQLRF06173) and oracle recommends using `XMLTABLE` instead:

```
SELECT value
FROM   TBL_DATA t
       CROSS JOIN
       XMLTABLE(
         '/root/MYData'
         PASSING t.XML_DATA
         COLUMNS value VARCHAR2(200) PATH 'text()'
       )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b0e76/7/1)**:

```
|       VALUE |
|-------------|
| test string |
```